# Python: Measuring playback time

Tags: python

I'm trying to measure the time it takes to play back X number of frames in Blender. In other packages, I'd usually just have something like:

```
bpy.ops.screen.animation_play()
```

and wrap a timer around that. However, in Blender when I try that in the console, it runs and returns immediately. So how can I measure the amount of time it takes to play back some frames in Blender?

EDIT:

This is what I've come up with, seems to work, but for some reason the handler/callback doesn't fire for frame 1.

```
import bpy
import time

start_frame = 2
end_frame = 250

start = time.time()
end = start

def my_handler(scene):
    global start
    global end
    global start_frame
    global end_frame
    if scene.frame_current == start_frame:
        start = time.time()
        print("Start time is {}".format(start))

    if scene.frame_current == end_frame:
        end = time.time()
        print("End time is {}".format(end))
        bpy.ops.screen.animation_cancel()
        elapsed_time = float(end - start)
        elapsed_frames = float(end_frame - start_frame)
        print("Elapsed time is: {}".format(end - start))
        print("FPS on average is: {}".format(elapsed_frames/elapsed_time))
        
bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre.append(my_handler)
bpy.ops.screen.animation_play()
```